# add prefix in mySQL

Tags: mysql, vb.net, prefix

I have this problem in adding prefix in a certain field
my field is

```
808 - 817(1)
```

or

```
808 - 818
```

what will I do to add prefix on it to be like this

```
a808 - 817(1)
```

and

```
a808 - 818
```

Comment: where is this data ? in some mysql table ?

Comment: yes... but not all cause I have some line number like 801, 802 that doesnt need prefix

Answer (score 0):

I used this

```
UPDATE `" + cboJob.Text + "` SET `Line Number` = CONCAT('a',`Line Number`) WHERE `Line Number` LIKE '%-%'
```